# How to use variable from constructor inside of methode?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys hope u are doing well, i'm new with python :)
so i have two issues the first how can i use the variable name from the **init** to my function **game()** which it use two args (those args whose make it realy difficult for me !) as u can see in code bellow:

```
# FUNCTION.py
class penGame():
def __init__(self):
    print("Welcome to Pendu Game")
    self.name = input("Enter your name: ") # IMPORT THIS VARIABLE FROM HERE

def game(self, letter, rword):
    letter = letter.lower()
    if letter in rword:
        for Id, Value in enumerate(rword):
            if Value == letter:
                donnee.default_liste[Id] = letter
    else:
        name2 = self.name # it deosn't work i got 1 missing arg when i run the code from MAIN.py
        print(f"try again {name} it's wrong ")
    print("-".join(donnee.default_liste))
```

The second issue is i need to use the same variable (**name**) from **init** in another module which is my main module and i couldn't use it cause i tried to create an object from class **penGame()** like:

```
myObject = penGame()
name2 = myObject.name
```

then use the **name2** inside of the **if** condition as u can see bellow but it doesn't work properly cause it run the init again which is not what i want actualy !
any idea how can i did it plz?

```
#MAIN.py
import donnee
from fonctions import penGame

random_word = random.choice(donnee.liste_words)  # creation of random word from liste_words
penGame()  #call the constructor
while donnee.counter < donnee.score:
    letter = input("Enter the letter: ")
    if penGame.check(letter):
        print("You cant use more one letter or numbers, try again !")  
    else:
        penGame.game(letter, random_word) # as u can see that's the reason cause i supposed to send 3 args instead of two ! but i only need those two !!?
    if penGame.check_liste():
        myObject = penGame() # that's cause runing the init everytime !!
        name2 = myObject.name
        print(f"congratulation {name2} you've guessed the word, your score is: {donnee.choice-donnee.counter} point.")
        break
    if penGame.loser():
        print(f"the word was {random_word.upper()} you have done your chances good luck next time.")
    donnee.counter += 1
```

Thank u in advance hope u help me with that and excuse my english if it wasn't that good  :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Error

You're calling the methods on the class penGame, not on a instance of penGame.
This causes your missing argument error because the method needs an instance of the class (the `self` parameter) but don't get one.
Instead use your variable (from the second solution):

```
if mygame.check(letter):
    print("You cant use more one letter or numbers, try again !")  
else:
    mygame.game(letter, random_word)
...
```

Replace `penGame` with `mygame` also in the other calls.

---

2. Error

Save the result of the call in a variable and you won't need to recreate it.

```
mygame = penGame()  # call the constructor
```

This line can then be removed:

```
myObject = penGame() # that causes the init to run again because it creates a new instance!
```